# Evaluate: $-T_1^{2k}+T_2^{2k}-T_3^{2k}+T_4^{2k}-T_5^{2k}+T_6^{2k}-\cdots+T_{2n}^{2k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

$T_n={n(n+1)\over 2}$, observing only the even terms of $T_n$ such as the series below

$$\color{red}{-1^2+3^2=8\times1^2}$$

$$\color{blue}{-1^2+3^2-6^2+10^2=8\times3^2}$$

$$\color{Red}{-1^2+3^2-6^2+10^2-15^2+21^2=8\times6^2}$$

$$\color{blue}{-1^2+3^2-6^2+10^2-15^2+21^2-28^2+36^2=8\times10^2}$$

---

$$-T_1^2+T_2^2-T_3^2+T_4^2-T_5^2+T_6^2-\cdots+T_{2n}^2$$

$$T_2^2-T_1^2+T_4^2-T_3^2+T_6^2-T_5^2-\cdots+T_{2n}^2-T_{2n-1}^2$$

$$8(1+2^3+3^3+\cdots n^3)$$

Well-known $1+2^3+3^3+\cdots +n^3=(1+2+3+\cdots n)^2=\left({n(n+1)\over 2}\right)^2=T_n^2$

so we have

$$8(1+2^3+3^3+\cdots n^3)=8T_n^2$$

My question is: **Can we find a general formula for** $$-T_1^{2k}+T_2^{2k}-T_3^{2k}+T_4^{2k}-T_5^{2k}+T_6^{2k}-\cdots+T_{2n}^{2k}?$$

$k:=1,2,3,...$

Comment: For small values of $k$ it will be possible to calculate the sum. I conjecture a general form will involve a sum up to $k$ and the Bernoulli numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for $k=2$ is
$$
4 n^2 (n + 1)^2 (2 n^4 + 4 n^3 - 2 n + 1)
\\= 16 T_n^2 (8 T_n^2- 4 T_n + 1)
$$
The formula for $k=3$ is
$$
n^2 (n + 1)^2 (32 n^8 + 128 n^7 + 96 n^6 - 160 n^5 - 61 n^4 + 294 n^3 - 33 n^2 - 228 n + 114)
\\= 8 T_n^2 (256 T_n^4 - 384 T_n^3 + 390 T_n^2 - 228 T_n + 57)
$$
Thus, an interesting question is to express the sum as a polynomial in $T_n$, as in [Faulhaber polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Faulhaber_polynomials).

Comment: If you made a mistake, I made the same. Merry Xmas.

Comment: Expression found with [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Eliminate+%5B%7BS%3D%3D4+n%5E2+(n+%2B+1)%5E2+(2+n%5E4+%2B+4+n%5E3+-+2+n+%2B+1),+x%3D%3D(n%5E2%2Bn)%2F2%7D,n%5D).

Answer (score 1):

$t_n
=n(n+1)/2
$.

Want
$s_n(k)
=\sum_{j=1}^{2n} (-1)^jt^{2k}_j
$.

Proceeding naively,

$\begin{array}\\
s_n(k)
&=\sum_{j=1}^{2n} (-1)^jt^{2k}_j\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{2n} (-1)^j(j(j+1)/2)^{2k}\\
&=2^{-2k}\sum_{j=1}^{2n} (-1)^j(j(j+1))^{2k}\\
&=2^{-2k}\sum_{j=1}^{2n} (-1)^jj^{2k}(j+1)^{2k}\\
\end{array}
$

At this point,
there seems to be
two ways to go:
expand the inner term
with the binomial theorem
or pair odd and even terms.

I'll try the latter.

$\begin{array}\\
s_n(k)
&=2^{-2k}\sum_{j=1}^{2n} (-1)^jj^{2k}(j+1)^{2k}\\
&=2^{-2k}\sum_{j=1}^{n} ((2j)^{2k}(2j+1)^{2k}-(2j-1)^{2k}(2j)^{2k})\\
&=2^{-2k}\sum_{j=1}^{n} (2j)^{2k}((2j+1)^{2k}-(2j-1)^{2k})\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n} j^{2k}((2j+1)^{2k}-(2j-1)^{2k})\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n} j^{2k}\sum_{i=0}^{2k}\binom{2k}{i}(2j)^i(1-(-1)^{2k-i})\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n} j^{2k}\sum_{i=1}^{k}\binom{2k}{2i-1}(2j)^{2i-1}2
\qquad\text{(difference is zero when i is even})\\
&=2\sum_{j=1}^{n} j^{2k}\sum_{i=1}^{k}\binom{2k}{2i-1}(2j)^{2i-1}\\
&=2\sum_{i=1}^{k}\binom{2k}{2i-1}\sum_{j=1}^{n} j^{2k}(2j)^{2i-1}\\
&=2\sum_{i=1}^{k}\binom{2k}{2i-1}2^{2i-1}\sum_{j=1}^{n} j^{2k+2i-1}\\
\end{array}
$

We can now
apply Faulhaber formula,
since the sums are
of odd powers.
This formula is
(from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula)

$\sum_{i=1}^n i^{2p+1}
=\dfrac1{2^{2p+2}(2p+2)}\sum_{q=0}^p
\binom{2p+2}{2q}(2-2^{2q})B_{2q}((2n+1)^{2p-2q+2}-1)
$

where the
$B_{2q}$
are the Bernoulli numbers.

This gives us,
with
$p=k+i-1$,
so
$2p+2
=2k+2i
$,

$\begin{array}\\
s_n(k)
&=2\sum_{i=1}^{k}\binom{2k}{2i-1}2^{2i-1}\sum_{j=1}^{n} j^{2k+2i-1}\\
&=2\sum_{i=1}^{k}\binom{2k}{2i-1}2^{2i-1}\dfrac1{2^{2k+2i}(2k+2i)}\sum_{q=0}^{k+i-1}
\binom{2k+2i}{2q}(2-2^{2q})B_{2q}((2n+1)^{2k+2i-2q+2}-1)\\
&=2\sum_{i=1}^{k}\binom{2k}{2i-1}2^{2i-1}\dfrac1{2^{2k+2i}(2k+2i)}\sum_{q=0}^{k+i-1}
\binom{2k+2i}{2q}(2-2^{2q})B_{2q}((2n+1)^{2(k+i-q+1)}-1)\\
\end{array}
$

We can 
reverse the order of summation
in the inner sum
to get a polynomial
in $2n+1$,
but I'll leave it at this.